# AngularJS: $resource with nested resources

Tags: angularjs, rest, restful-url

I am using AngularJS $resource model to REST API. I have got something like this:

```
angular.module('libraryapp')
    .factory('Book', function($resource){
        return $resource('books/:id');
    });
```

I am using in these way:

```
Book.get({ id: 42 }, function(book) {
    console.log(book);
});
```

But I also want an endpoint to a subresource, let's say:

```
GET /books/:id/comments
```

How should I define it in module? May I extend Book in some way, to use it like this

```
Book.get({ id: 42 }).Comment.query(function(comments) {
    console.log(comments);
});
```

Answer (score 8):

You can easily reach nested RESTful resources with AngularJS `$resource` definitions.

The clue is to understand how the `params` parameter of each *action* definition (in the list of `actions`) in the [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) definition works.  As the documentation says, it's an

> Optional set of pre-bound parameters for this action.  […]

```
angular.module('libraryApp').factory('Book', [
  '$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('books/:id/:subResource', {}, {
      comments: {  // The `comments` action definition:
        params: {subResource: 'comments'},
        method: 'GET'
      }
    });
  }
]);
```

Given the above definition, you should still be able to use `Book` as before. For example `Book.get({ id: 42 })` translates to a `GET books/42/` request.

However, given the new `:subResource` part of the `$resource` URL (`'books/:id/:subResource'`), you now *can* generate a

```
GET books/42/comments
```

request by calling *either* `Book.get({ id: 42, subResource: 'comments' })` or the much more short and elegant interface `Book.comments({ id: 42 })` defined as your `comments` action.

Comment: I know I answered this late, but if the answer works for you, it would be great if you accept it as the answer – so that other users can benefit from knowing that the answer works.  If you had any issues, please let me know.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that returned comments will be instances of Book resource. So if we call `Book.comments({ id: 42 }).$promise.then(function (comments) { comments[0].$get(); });` then this `$get` will try to `GET /books/<commend_id>` and this is of course is not right.

Comment: djxak, Do you have an alternative to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can't nest resources, but it's pretty simple to do what you're looking for:

You can define optional parameters which you can override in each resource (like `category` here) or even override the url (look at the `otherUrl` resource)

```
angular.module('libraryApp').factory('Book', [
  '$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('books/:id/:category', {}, {
      comments: {
        method: 'GET',
        action: 'category'
      },
      otherUrls: {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'books/:id/admin/:option'
      }
    });
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use Restangular instead as it handles nested resources and a clean and easy way.

Answer (score 0):

As djxak pointed out, adding actions to the resource means that the returned value is the containing resource type, not the sub-resource type.

I solved a similar problem by creating a new resource with the sub-resource URL and modifying the prototype of the containing resource to add a function:

```
angular.module('libraryapp')
    .factory('Book', function($resource){
        var bookUrl = 'books/:id',
            Book = $resource(bookUrl),
            BookComment = $resource(bookUrl + /comments");

        Book.prototype.getComments = function () {
            return BookComment.query({id: this.id});
        };

        return $resource('books/:id');
    });
```

The usage then becomes:

```
Book.get({ id: 42 }).getComments(function(comments) {
    console.log(comments);
});
```

The only downside I see with this approach is that if you have a separate "Comment" resource that is accessed via a different URL, you have to duplicate the $resource initialisation code for the alternative endpoint. This seems a minor inconvenience though.